# How to share a common customBuildCallbacks script between multiple Eclipse plug-ins

Tags: eclipse, pde

I am trying to avoid duplicating customBuildCallbacks.xml for all my plug-ins, when called from either PDE's headless build or the Eclipse GUI. I have in customBuildCallbacks.xml steps to generate code or modify the plug-in packaging that I:

- obviously want to run with the headless build
- would also like to run either when I export this plug-in from the GUI or from an external builder watching specific files in my plug-in

The headless build runs in a well defined environment, so I can set customBuildCallbacks.buildpath or even use a relative path in each plug-in's build.properties to point at my common customBuildCallbacks.xml. However, this is trickier from the GUI: that path is different for every developers since we do not have sources in the Eclipse workspace (we import projects from various locations due to our internal build process). I was hoping for every project to have an associated ant property holding its path on disk, similar to the ${workspace} variables exposed in various dialogs. I couldn't find anything useful though.

Does anyone have any experience doing this kind of things?

Thanks,

Romain

Comment: I have a long-winded "workaround stroke solution": write an ant builder for all plug-ins sharing a common customBuildCallbacks.xml that writes to say customBuildCallbacks.properties the location of the plug-in holding customBuildCallbacks.xml. Then one can pass onto this ant builder magic Eclipse properties, in particular ${workspace:/my.plugin}